# Update datebase and website behind the scenes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Imagine I have a website where people can submit to a party within a time limit. If the time limit reach the end, the party submission closes, and one column 'StatusClose' in the 'Party-table' will say 'Y' instead of 'N'. Users can no more submit to the specific party (in each row).

I can make this work if some user refreshes the site, to update the database, but I just feel its not the correct way of making it?

Is there a design, behind the scenes, that automatically closes a party, instead of it is depending on the refresh from a random user? I think of something automatic...

Comment: you could run a cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simple check in your php code before register a new user you check if  time limit  reached set your  StatusClose with true , or you can define [database trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) which will fire when time limit reached too

Comment: Your first suggestion: With a check, the first user who refresh after the time limit has been reached, will be the user who actually set the StatusClose as true. Right? Your second suggestion, with database trigger, the StatusClose can be set as true, at exactly the time when time limit has been reached. Am I right in that interpretation ?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you want an element on the page to change at a certain time with out the user having to refresh the page.

If so i would suggest adding a JavaScript code chat runs every few seconds and changes the element if the time you define is past.

Comment: Yep, javascript/AJAX would work for this without requiring a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cronjob to run every x minutes hours, seconds etc. Each time it run will execute a php script that would check you db and update it

## crontab -e

00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/